# Using bash glob in gradle exec task

Tags: bash, gradle, glob

I'm building a gradle `Exec` task that implies just invoking a basic `sed` command, let says:  `sed -i 's:some:substitution:' *`

*What is the proper syntax or gradle function/variable to make the `*` glob replaced by the file it would match in some bash/zsh shell?*

In other words, **how to trigger shell expansion**?

---

What I tried so far is :

```
task myTask(type: Exec){

    workingDirsome dir

    commandLine 'sed', '-i', 's:some:substitution:', "*"
}
```

but I get an error: `sed: can't read *: No such file or directory` , which is not so surprising.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to start the command wrapped in a shell:

```
commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'sed -i "s:some:substitution:" *'
```

Comment: Sure, however, in many systems `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Worked perfectly :). (with `sh`, so with `bash`)

Answer (score 0):

And here's an improvement which only runs `sed` if files really exists. It requires bash.

```
commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'shopt -s nullglob; f=(*); [[ ${f#[@]} -gt 0 ]] && sed -i "s:some:substitution:" -- "${f[@]}"'
```

Comment: It might look more stable but it is still prone to race conditions. `if file_exist(file) then read file;` will always be prone to race conditions

Comment: @hek2mgl It only does the check once. Just like `*`, `"${f[@]}"` is expanded at once. So if you consider race conditions here, so should you consider race conditions with `*`.

Comment: Yes, I consider race conditions with my code. I just wanted to point out that you can omit the additional checks as it will still be prone to race conditions. The only thing one can do is: doing it, check for errors and handle them if there are any.